# which framework contain dns_open function in iOS

Tags: iphone

dns_open is found in iPhoneOS5.0 in usr/include dns.h but I get a linker error. I can't seem to find the right framework for it.

on MacOSX this is probably found in System.framework but there is apparently no System.framework in iOS SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's in `libresolv.dylib`. Try adding that from the list of "frameworks" you get when you add one in Xcode.

Comment: got it though there are 3 frameworks in iOS 5.0 SDK with libresolv in their name I just selected the plain libresolve.dylib

Comment: Yep that's right. The others are just the usual symlinks. Picking `libresolv.dylib` is the right way to go.

Comment: @mattjgalloway, from where i will download libresolv.dylib  ?